# How to use Excel to combine two cells to point to another cell

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns of data each about 35 rows long, I have two input values, one calls on the row and the other calls on the column.

I am trying to combine these two input values to call on a specific cell, for instance it I input 3 and 17, it would know to go to cell C17 and output the cell for C17 so I could sum from that cell to to the bottom of the column at C36. So it would effectively be the same as =sum(C17:C36) but gathered from the input.

Comment: Look into `indirect`?

Comment: YES!!!!! I still have to manipulate it to my needs but it works!

Answer (score 1):

this is very fast:

```
=SUM( INDEX($A$1:$D$34,fromRow,fromCol): INDEX($A$1:$D$34,toRow,toCol) )
```

It is better to use index() rather than indirect(), because the latter is "volatile", and, if the model is large, it would slow it down a lot.